# MySQL remove quotes from middle of a string whilst maintaining the rest of the string intact

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, replace

I have some fields in a table that contain data similar to the following:

`{"item1":"stuff","item2":"12345","item3":0,"item4":"this field contains some data that has "quotes" in it that need to be removed","item5":"some other stuff","item6":"","item7":"","item8":"a.b.c.d.e.f"}`

I need to update the data to remove the quotes from the `item4` section, whilst maintaining the rest of the data intact.

e.g this:

`"item4":"this field contains some data that has "quotes" in it that need to be removed"`

needs to become:

`"item4":"this field contains some data that has quotes in it that need to be removed"`

I can remove the quotes without issue by doing:

`SET @dataval =('{"item1":"stuff","item2":"12345","item3":0,"item4":"this field contains some data that has "quotes" in it that need to be removed","item5":"some other stuff","item6":"","item7":"","item8":"a.b.c.d.e.f"}');`

`select REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@dataval,'"item4":"',-1),'","item5"',1),'"','');`

But of course, this loses the reset of the data.

Is there a way of doing this in one query, or am I going to need to do something like copy the data out to a temp table, remove the quotes, then do a `REPLACE` against the original data using the modified data?

Comment: *I have some fields in a table that contain data similar to the following:* What is the column datatype - some string type or JSON? Provide this not as alone value but as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: It is better to manipulate JSON strings as JSON, not character strings.

Comment: The column is a `text` field. Basically, I use an application that outputs JSON, but occasionally the JSON is invalid, so I am capturing the invalid entries, putting them in this text field so I can "correct" them and then re-process them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to update the column. All the mention steps can be found on this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1fffa8259a5cbbfa6f5ed7a9bd412cc3) and please always use a testing environment before using the suggested steps on production.

Suppose we have the following table:

```
create table test(
dataval varchar(255) );

insert into test values
('"item1":"stuff","item2":"12345","item3":0,"item4":"this field contains some data that has "quotes" in it that need to be removed","item5":"some other stuff","item6":"","item7":"","item8":"a.b.c.d.e.f"'),
('"item1":"stuff","item2":"12345","item3":0,"item4":"this uotes" in it that need to be removed","item5":"some other stuff","item6":"","item7":"","item8":"a.b.c.d.e.f"');
```

Below suggestion takes in consideration that `"item4":"` (which will be the start) and `","item5"` (which will be the end of the part of the string that we will update) will exist.

To select the string between `"item4":"` and `","item5"` we use:

```
select replace(substring_index(substring_index(dataval, '"item4":"', -1), '","item5":', 1),'"','') as new_dataval
from test;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> new_dataval
> this field contains some data that has "quotes" in it that need to be removed
> this uotes" in it that need to be removed
> ```

To remove the double quotes from the string use:

```
select replace(substring_index(substring_index(dataval, '"item4":"', -1), '","item5":', 1),'"','') as new_dataval
from test;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> new_dataval
> this field contains some data that has quotes in it that need to be removed
> this uotes in it that need to be removed
> ```

We can use above query to update the table:

```
UPDATE test
SET
dataval = REPLACE(dataval, substring_index(substring_index(dataval, '"item4":"', -1), '","item5":', 1), replace(substring_index(substring_index(dataval, '"item4":"', -1), '","item5":', 1),'"',''))
```

Now,  the table would be :

```
select dataval
from test;

dataval
"item1":"stuff","item2":"12345","item3":0,"item4":"this field contains some data that has quotes in it that need to be removed","item5":"some other stuff","item6":"","item7":"","item8":"a.b.c.d.e.f"
"item1":"stuff","item2":"12345","item3":0,"item4":"this uotes in it that need to be removed","item5":"some other stuff","item6":"","item7":"","item8":"a.b.c.d.e.f"
```

Comment: That is perfect cheers.